# How do I link to a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have JavaScript that makes it so that when you click on a string of text it creates a div that slides down and expands an area bellow it to show more information. I want to be able to have a link on a different page of my website that when clicked takes you to the page with the string of text ALREADY clicked on and expanded. How would I do this?

JSFidldle: http://jsfiddle.net/hr07tn16/2/

JavaScript:

```
$('.moreInfo').on('click', function(){
  var target = $(this).data('target');
  $('.expandable').not('.' + target).slideUp(500, function(){
    $('.' + target).slideDown(500, function(){
      });        
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="moreInfo" data-target="red">More Info</div> 
<div class="moreInfo" data-target="green">More Info</div> 
<div class="expandable red" style="display: none;">RED</div> 
<div class="expandable green" style="display: none;">GREEN</div>
```

CSS:

```
.expandable {
    width: 997px;
    height: 300px;
}
.red {
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: 380px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
.green {
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: 380px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add a hash to the link on your other page and, if the hash is present trigger the click. You could also use a flag to use the animation or not depending on whether is an automatic trigger or a manual one.

Comment: How would I make it so if the hash is present then the click is triggered? I am very new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is redirecting to that page with a POST variable set indicating the element you would like expanded. Then on the page being directed to, have an onLoad() function which checks if the variable is set and then does what you want if it is.

[onLoad()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload)